# Is there a way to load a function from the htm that you're loading with .load()? JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent, onload

In my main window main.htm I have a div button that loads another htm file into a large div when clicked. I use .load() to achieve this:

```
 $('#mainpanel').load("search.htm");
```

There is a function in "search.htm" called `test()` which only consists of `alert("hi");` and I want this to load when `search.htm` is loaded into the div. I used the body `onload` tag and `window.onload = test;` and even `$( document ).ready()` but nothing works. It only works if I access search.htm on its own, but if I access it through `main.htm` it does't alert "hi". Is there a way to use `.load()` to load the page and a function? or is there a way to get the function the `onload` when I select the div that loads the page?

Comment: Couldn't you write the script in an external file and just insert this script into your page when you grab `search.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onload / document ready will only fire once (when the parent document is loaded)

Either add a

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    test();
</script>
```

to the end of the `search.htm` (so it's executed after everything else in the page has been parsed) or call `test();` from the parent page after the load completes (via a callback)...

```
$('#mainpanel').load("search.htm", function(){
    test();
});
```

It depends which page you want to be responsible for executing the function. In the latter case, the parent page needs to know the name of the function in search which may or may not fit your design.

Comment: OMG didnt even think of the first idea, i feel stupid. It works now. Thank you.

Comment: No worries at all. If either of our answers helped, consider upvoting and/or accepting using the arrows/ticks on the left hand side. All the best and hopefully see you around in future.

Answer (score 0):

Using `window.onload` or `$( document ).ready()` doesn't make sense because the document is most likely already loaded when you run that function.

You can pass a callback to `.load` and access the function inside there. The callback is executed when the other page is loaded:

```
$('#mainpanel').load("search.htm", function() {
    test();
});
```

Of course `test` must be in global scope for this to work.

---

As always, it's advisable to the read the **documentation** of the methods you are using: https://api.jquery.com/load/.